# What's wrong with this code? I keep getting errors and, it just doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip-geolocation

The script reveals the appropriate div if the user resides in a specific place with the help of MaxMind's database.

But, since I'm still getting my feet wet this little snippet of code I've put together just doesn't want to work.

What am I getting wrong here?

(edited with more info below - thanks everyone for the heads up about clarification! so helpful)

$geoip_city is a global variable provided by the MaxMind database. It returns a value based on the user's IP which corresponds to listed entries. In this case I'm looking for users in specific cities like Toronto or Vancouver.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($geoip_city() == $geoip_city('Vancouver')){
     document.getElementById('vizPlayer').style.display = "block";
    }else if ($geoip_city() == $geoip_city('Toronto')){
      document.getElementById('vizPlayer').style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Comment: What errors? What do you mean "doesnt want to work"? Have you tried debugging to see what are the values you get at each stage?

Comment: Show us what `$geoip_city()` is.

Comment: Check your error console. Then post the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Much appreciated for the valuable feedback. Too bad that -5 makes me want to not use this site anymore. What's the point of a beginner trying to learn and get answers if people shoot them down so fast...

Comment: $geoip_city is a global variable provided by the MaxMind database. It returns a value based on the user's IP which corresponds to listed entries. In this case I'm looking for users in specific cities like Toronto or Vancouver.

Comment: The downvotes are because of lack of information. You say you get errors, but no info about what the errors say,. That means we have not all the information needed to be able to help you. If you edit the question itself, and provide more info, it might be that some of the down-votes are taken back. (Actually the system here don't allow us to take back the down-vote until you do an edit...)

Comment: @can SO is a huge community and there are many new users posting every day. Without the strict moderation, the site would become useless very quickly. Instead of complaining, read the [faq]. The problem is *never* that somebody is a beginner, but usually one of the following (a) they provided too little information (b) they didn't bother to Google beforehand (c) they want somebody else to to their work for them (d) they failed to invest enough effort in writing a good question.

Comment: @dandan78  & awe Thanks to both of you! Comments like this are incredibly helpful. I didn't even know there was a faq, but now that I see it I'll be sure to pass it's url on to others that need help as well. More info added and I'll be sure to clarify much more in future use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how document.ready should look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){


});
```